# shifting array elements

Tags: c++

I've been able to learn a lot about array manipulating, but was wondering how to go about shifting the elements around in the array, I'd like to try to add one more sot in the array initialized it with 0 and shift the elements around.

Comment: Do you want to insert an element into the beginning? is that a plain C array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have an array:

```
char*  cArr = new char[20];

for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    cArr[i] = i;
}
```

If you want to shift the array to add something at a specific index, you'll have to first setup a backup pointer to the old array, make a new array, and copy the data over. Actually, you'd have to consider doing this for a lot of the array manipulation you want to do if the size is going to change.

```
// create backup and new array one larger
char* backup = cArr;
cArr = new char[20 + 1];

// lets say you want to shift the 3rd position to the right, which in 0-indexing is 2
int shiftIndex= 2;

// copy the unshifted data from the backup to the beginning of the new array
memcpy(cArr, backup, shiftIndex);    
// copy the shifted data the the later part of the new array
memcpy(cArr + shiftIndex + 1, backup + shiftIndex, 20 - shiftIndex);

// cleanup the backup array
delete [] backup;
backup = nullptr;
```

Now you have unset data, or a open spot in the array at cArr[shiftIndex]. So, this is just one example of what you can do.  [disclaimer, I did not type this example out in a compiler, and I'm busy studying for a midterm, so I apologize if there are any errors]
Anyway, I hope this helps you!

And for reference, check this out: [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/).

Comment: You use `delete` to release an array allocated with `new[]` - that's undefined behavior. You should use `delete[]` or better yet just use `std::vector`.

Comment: @sharptooth The person who asked the question said they wanted to learn about array manipulation, otherwise I would have mentioned vector or list.

Answer (score 1):

First I want to mention, that shifting elements in the array is an algorithmically expensive problem: it is O(N) and if you are going to do it frequently you should consider using linked list instead, for which the insertion is a O(1) operation (however you lose the indexing capabilities and you need more memory to store your data). Now the code to do what you've been asking for:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**) {
    vector<int> rands(5);
    generate(rands.begin(), rands.end(), rand);

    cout << "Initial array:\n";
    copy(rands.begin(), rands.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));

    vector<int> zeros(3);
    fill(zeros.begin(), zeros.end(), 0);

    vector<int>::size_type insert_position = 3, insert_count = 2;

    // Here's the actual insertion
    // insert from other collection:
    rands.insert(rands.begin() + insert_position, zeros.begin(), zeros.end());
    // insert a value into the beginning:
    rands.insert(rands.begin(), insert_count, -1);

    cout << "Initial array with inserted elements:\n";
    copy(rands.begin(), rands.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

So inserting is actually a method of the vector. Calling it would resize the vector, copy elements to their new shifted location and then copy elements from other data structure into their new positions. Resizing the vector might also trigger the allocation of new memory chunk, copying the old elements into it and deleting the old array. If you use c-style arrays rather than vectors, than you would have to worry about all the aforementioned steps yourself.

Comment: +1 for your post, but not as an answer to his question as he asked about learning of manipulation of arrays. Yes he should know how to do this using the std lib, but if he wants to be a more well-rounded programmer he should be able to know how to do what he asked about.  Besides, the manipulation of a contiguous array is basically what's going on behind a vector, and he could learn to roll his own class if he wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with arrays. Have a look at STL and specifically at [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) data set.

Comment: Why `std::list<>` and not `std::vector<>` or `std::deque<>`, which are much closer in spirit to an array?

Comment: You can use vector and deque, but list is the simplest type that is very efficient at inserting elements anywhere at the container. I believe that this is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Agreed to some extent, however I think a more fundamental property of arrays that should not be disregarded is random-access, which `std::list<>` of course does not provide.

Comment: You are right about this. It depends on what feature is more important to the user.

Comment: In most uses, `vector` or `deque` will outperform `list` even when inserting into the middle.  The real argument for `list`, in certain cases, is that insertions and erasures don't invalidate iterators, like they do with `vector`.